# Why is Visual Studio 2010 changing my Design window positions after returning to Design mode from Build mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been having an issue with Visual Studio 2010 that is driving me completely bonkers. The general problem is that Visual Studio 2010 does not seem to be remembering my window positions. (Visual Studio 2010, v.10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel on Windows XP SP3.)

Now, I am aware that Visual Studio 2010 has different window layouts for Build and Design mode. I have come to accept this as there are some things in life I cannot change. If I could turn off this feature, I would be over-joyed, but I do not think it is possible.

My biggest issue at this point is that Visual Studio 2010 doesn't remember the window positions in Design mode after going into Build mode and returning to Design mode.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate this issue:

[image: Screenshot 1 -- Design mode.]

Imagine me coding. OK, time to build.

[image: Screenshot 2 -- Build mode.]

OK, the window layouts changed. This is annoying, but whatever. Let's go back to design mode.

[image: Screenshot 3 -- Back to Design mode.]

This looks OK, but WAIT -- why don't the windows return to their previous position?

[image: Screenshot 4 -- Why won't you line up?!]

I'm using a small Visual Studio window size here, but as the red box shows -- there is a difference. Why does this happen and what can I do to fix this issue? It is driving the OCD in me completely nuts. It doesn't look like a big change in these screen shots, but when I have my VS instance maximized across my two monitors (configured to display as one continuous desktop, instead of two desktops) -- it's a very noticeable and annoying change.

Possible problems that I thought were causing this issue:

- I store my working copy in a Dropbox folder. I work from that dropbox folder. However, I've tried this same issue with Dropbox turned off and reproduced the above issue.
- Corrupted settings file. I tried this with a new MVC application, saved it outside of the Dropbox, and the same thing happened.
- Windows XP issue. I know I need to upgrade, but unfortunately that is not always an option. If Windows 7 doesn't have this issue, I will gladly upgrade.
- @Shtong has answered below that I should use a dual monitor setup with different desktop configurations and install [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/). While this will technically fix the problem (I can now have two sets of mixed tabs and the sizes do not change) - the docking positions are forgotten instead. This means that if I dock the Solution Explorer to the right in design mode, then build, then go back to design mode -- my docked window is no longer docked.

I've also had this same problem in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Thanks, Henrik, for your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try installing the [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) that lets you split your editors into different windows, making two windows and attaching each to one monitor (instead of having one stretched over the two monitors) ? That way each window should fit into its monitor like every other window and your problem should disappear.

Comment: Thank you, so much. While I would prefer to stretch VS over two monitors (I like the long Start bar) -- installing VS Productivity Power Tools does indeed fix the issue. I can make a new window, and then add tabs to that new window (I was unable to do this without Power Tools.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't actually solve the problem either. While I can now have multiple-tabs across two monitors, and this is remembered by Visual Studio when going between Design and Build modes, internally docked positions are not 'remembered.' For instance, in design mode, when I dock the Solution Explorer to the right window -- this dock is forgotten when I build and then return to design mode.

I would just like a consistent experience between design and build modes, and this can't seem to figure out how to make this possible.

Comment: I just did the test and VS always resets the second window configuration for me as well :/ ... Sorry !